# I have created a class and I would like to also create an interface to insert the values in it instead of code itself. How can I do this?

Tags: java

My variables within the code like as follows:

```
public class ExperimentRunner {
   
    private static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMddhhmmssSSS");
    private static ExperimentConfig config = new Config_1();
    private static int vmCnt = 9;
    private static int hostCnt = 3;
    private static int userCnt = 3;
    private static int workloadLength = 60;
    private static int experimentCnt = 1;
    private static boolean logTrace = true;
    private static double priorityUpdateInterval = 1;

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ...

    }
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to create an GUI interface to specify all these values of the variables instead of specifying within the code. Could you please help me regarding this?

Comment: Please specify _which_ GUI interface you may need help with? [Swing (see Oracle tutorial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), [JavaFX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/index.htm)?  Which tutorials did you try and which issues did you face?

Comment: Actually, I'm using Swing and I have now imported awt and event before class definition.

Comment: import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

Comment: stqckoverflow is not a tutorial site so please find some tutorials instead and/or some articles about Swing to study.

Comment: Yes sure, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, create application using Swing or JavaFX (libraries for creating graphic interface) or create console application. Second way is easier if you are new in Java. To get data from user you need to use class `Scanner`. You can learn about it in every tutorial for beginners like this article: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/scanner

Comment: Why should OP use the Scanner class to get data from the user when using a GUI framework like Swing or JavaFX? I fail to see the logic in this recommendation.

Comment: OP don't specified his experience with Java but for me he look like beginner. Java and Swing are not easy. If he understand Java then he can use that libraries but if he is beginner better way is use Scanner to get data from a user.

Comment: many thanks for you guys. Now, I'm reading some tutorials regarding Swing. Actually, I have not already used Swing as I'm only use java for simulations. However, I will edit the codes once I finish it and if any problem occurs, I will share it here.

Comment: First of all I think clear that OP wants to use a GUI but if we put that aside it is your wording that is strange since you first write about Swing and JavaFX and then in the next sentence claim that "...you _need_ to use class Scanner" so at least introduce Scanner as an option to using a GUI by changing the text because now it reads like Swing and JavaFX can't be used for user input

Comment: I mean that if OP is beginner, he shouldn't start with Swing or JavaFX. Better way would be use Scanner for get data from user instead constants in code. But if OP understand Java yet, nothing stand in the way to use one of above libraries.